# Gradle, extracting a dependency zip and using the content in its file?

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I have a Gradle build project that is dependent on another project. My project is supposed to pull a zip archive from the other project and extract the archive. One of the files inside the archive is called "name.txt", and inside it is a string that I need to pass as an argument inside my "build" task.

```groovy
def unzippedDir = file('build/dependencies/unzippedDir').getAbsolutePath()

configurations {
  zipArchive
}

dependencies {
  ziparchive "<path>"
}

task unzip(type:Copy) {
  into unzippedDir from zipTree(configurations.zipArchive.singleFile)
}

task build {
  dependsOn unzip
  def name = new File(unzippedDir + '/name.txt').text
  // <the test of the build steps that uses the "name" variable>
}
```

But I am getting a "No File or Directory" error for "name.txt". Am I doing something wrong?

What I am seeing in the extracted directory though, is that only one of the files inside the zip archive ended up in the unzippedDir. "name.txt" is not there even though another file is. Does this mean I did something wrong with the unzip task?

Comment: What I am seeing in the extracted directory though, is that only one of the files inside the zip archive ended up in the unzippedDir. "name.txt" is not there even though another file is. Does this mean I did something wrong with the unzip task?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this:

and check your configuration name because of a spelling mistake there.

```
def unzippedDir = "$buildDir/dependencies/unzippedDir" 

task unzip(type: Copy) {
    configurations.zipArchive.asFileTree.each {
        from(zipTree(it))
    }
    into unzippedDir
}

build.dependsOn unzip
```

Comment: Does this mean I have to point archiveDir at the location where the dependency archive is stored? Where is that?

Comment: @JimmyT archive dir is the directory where your archive is. I dont know where you have it.

Comment: the archive is pulled down from an artifactory repository.  It is stored somewhere automatically by gradle. So I do not know explicity where it is.

Comment: i see you didnt mention that ;p lthen yes you are going to fetch it from artifactory. i Iwll edit the answer

Comment: I think the key here is that somehow my unzip task ends up putting only one file into unzippedDir (missing name.txt that I actually need). I'm not sure what the proper property is besides "singleFile" to use inside zipTree. I've been trying to find documentation for it but no luck so far.

Comment: @JimmyT try this i just pulled a dependency and unpacked it with this.

Comment: Fantastic, this is it. Thank you.

Comment: Why might you get `InvalidUserDataException: Cannot change strategy of configuration ':zipArchive' after it has been resolved.` when doing this?

Comment: Probably because a change is attempted at execution stage to an entity that has been set up at configuration change. Gradle makes distinction between these two phases.